# I want to create isolated environment for all teammates to run their code

Tags: ubuntu, docker, virtual-machine, containers, isolation

Suppose I have a ubuntu machine(server).
And 3 team members, they all are working on their separate applications :
    1. PHP
    2. Node
    3. Java

Now when they push their code, I need to be able to run their code so that they can test it. Moreover, the app must be kept running and their environment should be different.

I was thinking of creating docker containers for each of them, but that takes about 350MB of space, which not seems to be good if the team grows to 100s of people.

Please suggest me something or I need to stick with docker container?

Thanks

Comment: can you show your Dockerfiles? It is often possible to get much smaller images.

Comment: It is still very unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you came to the conclusion that you need `3` containers because you have `3` applications.

- If you go from `3` people to a `100`, that does not necessarily mean that you will need `100 - 3 = 97` more containers. You may still work on only those `3` applications. Your concern may not be warranted here.
- `350 MB * 100 = 35 GB`, that is still very cheap for the cost of doing business.

You should use Dockerfiles if it makes your development easier.